VAE Loss Decreases But Reconstruction Doesn't Improve
I am having trouble with the reconstruction images not working at all. Here's how I'm performing a single update step. I understand that a simpler implementation is possible for a regular VAE, but due to other constraints, I need to implement it this way. Therefore, I would like to know if there are any mistakes in this implementation, rather than asking for a more efficient one. The zeros_like_batchstats function returns an object with the same structure as the input, but with all values set to zero.
@jax.jit
def train_step(
    rng: jax.random.PRNGKey,
    state_enc: TrainState,
    state_dec: TrainState,
    imgs: jax.Array,
) -> Tuple[TrainState, TrainState, Dict]:

    ((mean, logvar), enc_mutated_vars), vjp_fn_enc = jax.vjp(
        lambda params: state_enc.apply_fn(
            {"params": params, "batch_stats": state_enc.batch_stats},
            imgs, train=True, mutable=["batch_stats"]
        ),
        state_enc.params,
    )
    z, vjp_fn_latents = jax.vjp(
        lambda mean, logvar: sample_z(rng, mean, logvar),
        mean, logvar
    )

    def recon_loss_fn(dec_params, latent_features):
        # Get reconstructed images from the decoder
        recon, mutated_vars = state_dec.apply_fn(
            {'params': dec_params, 'batch_stats': state_dec.batch_stats},
            latent_features, train=True, mutable=['batch_stats']
        )
        recon_loss = jnp.mean(jnp.sum(binary_cross_entropy_fn(recon, imgs), axis=(1, 2, 3), keepdims=True))
        return recon_loss, mutated_vars

    recon_loss_grads_fn = jax.value_and_grad(recon_loss_fn, argnums=(0, 1), has_aux=True)
    (recon_loss, dec_mutated_vars), (grads_dec, graz_z) = recon_loss_grads_fn(state_dec.params, z)
    grads_enc_recon=vjp_fn_enc((vjp_fn_latents(graz_z), {"batch_stats": zeros_like_batchstats(state_enc.batch_stats)}))[0]

    # Compute kld_loss
    def kld_loss_fn(mean, logvar):
        kld_loss = jnp.mean(jnp.sum(-0.5 * (1 + logvar - mean ** 2 - jnp.exp(logvar)), axis=1))
        return kld_loss

    kld_loss_grads_fn = jax.value_and_grad(kld_loss_fn, argnums=(0, 1))
    kld_loss, grads_mean_and_logvar = kld_loss_grads_fn(mean, logvar)
    grads_enc_kld = vjp_fn_enc((grads_mean_and_logvar, {"batch_stats": zeros_like_batchstats(state_enc.batch_stats)}))[0]

    # Compute gradient for encoder
    grads_enc = jax.tree_util.tree_map(lambda x, y: x + y, grads_enc_recon, grads_enc_kld)

    # Stores the gradients and batch statistics\
    state_enc = state_enc.apply_gradients(grads=grads_enc, batch_stats=enc_mutated_vars["batch_stats"])
    state_dec = state_dec.apply_gradients(grads=grads_dec, batch_stats=dec_mutated_vars["batch_stats"])

    metrics = {
        "train/recon_loss": recon_loss,
        "train/kld_loss": kld_loss,
    }
    return state_enc, state_dec, metrics

I have confirmed that there are no issues with the shapes, and the loss is also decreasing.
